# Ruby returning from inside a method but outside a loop

Tags: ruby, loops, methods, return

Try running this code.

When method1 is run, the hash is returned twice, meaning the hash is returned and printed as intended by the 'puts method1().inspect' command.

When method2 is run, and the loop is exited second time-around, by typing "no" or "n", a bunch of seemingly random numbers are printed, instead of a lovely hash. Why is this????

```
def method1

    loop do
        print "Item name: "
        item_name = gets.chomp

        print "How much? "
        quantity = gets.chomp.to_i

        hash = {"Item"=> item_name, "quantity"=> quantity}
        puts hash.inspect

        return hash
    end

end

puts method1().inspect


def method2

    loop do
        print "Item name: "
        item_name = gets.chomp

        print "How much? "
        quantity = gets.chomp.to_i

        hash = {"Item"=> item_name, "quantity"=> quantity}
        puts hash.inspect

        print "Add another item? "
        answer = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if (answer == "no") || (answer == "n")
    end

    return hash

end

puts method2().inspect
```

Comment: `hash` there isn't what you think it is; the `hash` inside the loop is visible only to that block. If you use a variable name that isn't already a method you'll get a very different result :)

Comment: Also not an answer to you question but just a note. Your `hash` variable will only hold the last result because you are overwriting it on each loop using `hash =`. Look at `Hash#merge`

Answer (score 2):

You've accidentally discovered the [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Object.html#method-i-hash) method.  You don't declare `hash` outside the loop, so it is not in scope to return at the end.  Instead, it returns the `hash()` method value, which is a big negative number for that instance.

Fire up irb, and just type hash, you'll see the same thing:

```
(505)⚡️ irb
2.1.2 :001 > hash
 => -603961634927157790
```

So instead, try this:

```
def method2
    hash = {}
    loop do
        # ...
```

Also be aware you aren't adding to the hash, you're re-creating it every time.

Answer (score 0):

In `method2`, you're trying to return something (`hash`) that has gone out of scope.

In `method1`, you're still inside the loop where `hash` was defined when you return it. In `method2`, you're outside of the scope where `hash` was defined, so it has an undocumented outcome. Redefined `method2` like so:

```
def method2
    hash = nil

    loop do
        print "Item name: "
        item_name = gets.chomp

        print "How much? "
        quantity = gets.chomp.to_i

        hash = {"Item"=> item_name, "quantity"=> quantity}
        puts hash.inspect

        print "Add another item? "
        answer = gets.chomp.downcase
        break if (answer == "no") || (answer == "n")
    end

    return hash

end
```

Now, even though `hash` was initially set to nil, its scope includes the entire method, and the value will be retained.

Comment: You might want to fix this method to actually append to a the hash since that seems to be what the OP wants but the OP seems to misunderstand how assignment works.